# Me ajudem com um foreach array php

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Estou usando o cURL do PHP para pegar um json de uma api.
Os dados estão sendo armazenados corretamente em uma variavel.
Porém quando tento exibir os dados com um foreach da erro na linha onde esta o foreach:

O json que vem do site é assim:

```
[{"Nome":"Sabrina","Sobrenome":"Freitas"}, 
 {"Nome":"Maria","Sobrenome":"Sebastiana"}, 
 {"Nome":"Evandro","Sobrenome":"Martins"}]

<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.teste.com.br/json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$data = array();

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);


foreach($data as $key => $valor){


    echo "Nome: $valor->Nome <br>";
    echo "Sobrenome: $valor->Sobrenome <br><hr>";


}

?>
```

o PHP me retorna esse erro:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /storage/ssd3/794/5409794/public_html/index.php on line 17

Alguem sabe onde estou errando ?
Desde já agradeço

Comment: mas já vem em formato json ou faltou converter?

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de fechar a aspas simples na linha curl_setopt

Comment: tente concatenar o valor no foreach assim: `echo "Nome: ".$valor->Nome."<br>";`

Comment: rray ?? Já vem em formato json

Comment: adventistaam ?? concatenaando não deu certo

Comment: acho que tem que fazer isso: `json_decode($data, true);` antes de fazer o foreach, além disso, é sempre bom verificar se tem dado para fazer o foreach... tipo: `if(count($data)) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu json pode retornar NULL por vários motivos:

Vou lista-los abaixo:

```
JSON_ERROR_DEPTH // A profundidade máxima da pilha foi excedida

JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH // JSON inválido ou mal formado

JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR // Erro de caractere de controle, possivelmente codificado incorretamente

JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX // Erro de sintaxe

JSON_ERROR_UTF8 // caracteres UTF-8 malformado , possivelmente codificado incorretamente
```

**[Veja mais no manual.](http://de.php.net/json_last_error)**

Para descobrir qual o problema você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
```

A maioria das vezes o problema está relacionado ao `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`. E se for isso, existe algumas formas de tentar resolver. Como:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($data));
$data = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Existe também esse script:

```
function safe_json_encode($value, $options = 0, $depth = 512){ 
    $encoded = json_encode($value, $options, $depth); 
    switch (json_last_error()) { 
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE: return $encoded; 
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH: return 'Maximum stack depth exceeded'; 
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH: return 'Underflow or the modes mismatch'; 
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR: return 'Unexpected control character found'; 
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX: return 'Syntax error, malformed JSON'; 
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8: 
            $clean = utf8ize($value); 
            return safe_json_encode($clean, $options, $depth); 
        default: return 'Unknown error'; 

    } 
} 

function utf8ize($mixed) { 
    if (is_array($mixed)) { 
        foreach ($mixed as $key => $value) { 
            $mixed[$key] = utf8ize($value); 
        } 
    } else if (is_string ($mixed)) { 
        return utf8_encode($mixed); 
    } 
    return $mixed; 
}
```

Que você utilizaria assim:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = isafe_json_encode($data);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

*Links úteis:*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199017/how-to-solve-json-error-utf8-error-in-php-json-decode

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call

Comment: o json dele está retornando o valor desejado, como string, o problema está como ele processa a informação recebida. Ele tenta iterar a string sem antes converter para objeto/array.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre não mauro. Nos comentários da sua resposta ele citou que o valor retornado é NULL. Veja lá.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre o valor retornado do decode é null! A string ele está conseguindo resgatar. O problema é na conversão.

Comment: resolveu com a sua ajuda e a do Mauro veja:

Comment: $data = array();

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($data));
$data = json_decode($data, true);

curl_close($ch);


foreach($data as $key => $valor){


    echo "Nome: {$valor["Nome"]} <br>";
   
}

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas não esquece de aprovar por favor

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas deu um trabalho fazer essa resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Uma pena que só posso aprovar 1 resposta né. mas a resposta do Mauro foi de muita ajuda também agradeço aos dois

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas obrigado! Abraço!

Comment: mantive o meu código só inclui ( $data = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($data)); ) e ( $data = json_decode($data, true);) o resto a resposta é do Mauro mesmo mas valeu Andrei foi de muita ajuda mesmo.

Comment: Sim! Estava certa a resposta do @MauroAlexandre também, graças a ele você pode identificar o erro do UTF8

Comment: @RodrigoPereiradeFreitas tranquilo! Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Sendo breve, o PHP não reconhece o contéudo de `$data` como um objeto, nem como array (referenciado no foreach), para isso é preciso que você converta a `string` recebida para o formato correto:

```
$data = array();

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($data, true); //novo código
curl_close($ch);


foreach($data as $key => $valor){


    echo "Nome: {$key["Nome"]} <br>";
    echo "Sobrenome: {$key["Sobrenome"]} <br><hr>";


}
```

desse modo você poderá iterar o objeto, tanto como array. Você pode utilizar `var_dump()` antes do `foreach` para ver o conteúdo e tipo de `$data`, assim fica mais fácil encontrar o problema.

Comment: Mauro, quando faço um var_dump() ele informa que é uma string ({string(193387)) continua dando erro no foreach mesmo fazendo o que falou

Comment: Atualizei, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Quando dou um (echo $data ) aparecem os dados todos

Comment: Rodrigo, você precisa executar o `var_dump()` antes do `foreach` e depois do novo código `$data = json_decode();`

Comment: certo, primeiro fiz $data = json_decode($data,true) depois fiz o var_dump(&data) aparece o resultado = NULL

Comment: sem fazer o $data = json_decode($data,true) e chamando o var_dump($data) o resultado é                                       
string(193387)"[{"Nome":"Sabrina","Sobrenome":"Freitas"}, 
 {"Nome":"Maria","Sobrenome":"Sebastiana"}, 
 {"Nome":"Evandro","Sobrenome":"Martins"}]"

Comment: Caso possa passar o link do site que fornece a API, seria de melhor para poder ajudar, estou simulando na minha máquina com esse mesmo código e está funcionando.

Comment: cara o link é restrito e para acessar precisa de login e senha.

Comment: Se eu pudesse trocar a senha eu até passaria mas não controlo isso infelizmente

Comment: Tente refazer o código de acordo com a resposta, sem o var_dump. Atualizei novamente.

Comment: esta dando erro na linha do foreach